# Assigning req.body to a variable

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to post data from a leaflet layer and then run it through express and return an array using a third-party module.

If I stipulate the id needed in the call like this

```
forecast = msw.forecast(1)
```

it works fine. When I try to use the spot_id coming from the post request it gives me this:

```
TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'units' in 1
```

Here's the what I'm using on my node.js server. Any help would be really appreciated.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var msw = require('msw-api');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

msw.set({ apiKey: 'my-api-key' , units: 'UK' });


app.post('/', function(req, res){
    spot_id = req.body.spot_id
    forecast = msw.forecast(spot_id).then(function (forecast) {
    res.send(forecast)
});
    });

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Listening on port 3000!');
});
```

Comment: This question is not related to Leaflet.js (as the tags suggest) but it's related to https://github.com/justinjmoses/msw-api

Comment: Yeah you're right. I'll remove.

Comment: @MattT can you please **console.log** the req.body.spot_id to see what comes from the request. It is important A) to know that spot_id of req.body is not undefined B) whether parsing the spot_id to integer and then passing it would make any difference or not?

Comment: @Raf I have tried that and it logs the spot_id fine when I run the server. Is there a method for parsing to int then?

Comment: I would replace the spot_id with **var spot_id = parseInt(req.body.spot_id)** and see what happens.

Comment: It works, you are a absolute star! I should have asked here sooner?

Comment: Do you want to answer the question or should I just refer to your comments?

Comment: I will put an answer, can't say no to that haha

Comment: Thank you again. I am really happy about that result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments the value of the **req.body.spot_id** is string by default and the `msw.forecast(spot_id)` requires an `integer` as its argument hence the error.

All you have to do is parse the `spot_id` to `integer` as shown below:

```
var spot_id = parseInt(req.body.spot_id)
```

Before feeding it to `forecast` as argument.